# Migrating from Squeryl 0.9.5 to 0.9.6

Tags: scala, squeryl

I am trying to migrate an existing application fron SQueryl 0.9.5 to 0.9.6, in order to make use of the new [extended field types](https://github.com/max-l/squeryl-extended-field-types-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/MyCustomTypes.scala). I am now to the point where the application and its tests compile, but I get a runtime error as soon as I try to load a `Schema`.

A portion of the rather long stacktrace includes this:

```
[error] ModelSpec.withDB(ModelSpec.scala:14)
[error] BucketSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BucketSpec.scala:11)
[error] BucketSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BucketSpec.scala:11)
[error] Usupported native type models.fields.DateTime,models.fields.DateTime
[error] class java.util.UUID -> java.util.UUID --> null
[error] class java.lang.String -> java.lang.String --> null
[error] class scala.Enumeration$Value -> scala.Enumeration.Val --> null
[error] class [B -> byte[] --> null
[error] class java.lang.Float -> java.lang.Float --> null
[error] class java.util.Date -> java.util.Date --> null
[error] class scala.Enumeration$Val -> scala.Enumeration.Val --> null
[error] class java.lang.Integer -> java.lang.Integer --> null
[error] class java.lang.Double -> java.lang.Double --> null
[error] class java.sql.Timestamp -> java.sql.Timestamp --> null
[error] class java.lang.Byte -> java.lang.Byte --> null
[error] class java.lang.Boolean -> java.lang.Boolean --> null
[error] class scala.math.BigDecimal -> scala.math.BigDecimal --> null
[error] class java.lang.Long -> java.lang.Long --> null
[error] org.squeryl.internals.Utils$.throwError(Utils.scala:95)
[error] org.squeryl.internals.FieldMapper$$anonfun$get$1.apply(FieldMapper.scala:299)
[error] org.squeryl.internals.FieldMapper$$anonfun$get$1.apply(FieldMapper.scala:299)
```

Having a look at the [source](https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/internals/FieldMapper.scala) it seems that the exception comes from the failure of the `FieldMapper.lookup` method, namely the line

```
if(!c.isPrimitive)
  registry.get(c)
```

As far as I understand, mapping for classes are loaded via the `register` method, and in particular for the native types we have the lines

```
  protected def initialize {
    import PrimitiveTypeSupport._

    register(byteTEF)
    register(intTEF)
    register(longTEF)
    register(floatTEF)
    register(doubleTEF)
    register(bigDecimalTEF)

    register(binaryTEF)
    register(booleanTEF)
    register(stringTEF)
    register(timestampTEF)
    register(dateTEF)
    register(uuidTEF)
```

I am not sure how to load my personal extended primitive types in this registry, so that they will be used correctly.

> Does anyone know what is the mechanism through which I should enable extended primitive types?

**EDIT:**

Here is my model - it seems to me that it looks like the "official" example, save for the fact that I am not using directly Joda time but a thin wrapper around it, which is called `DateTime`

```
object DateTime extends PrimitiveTypeMode {
  import org.squeryl._
  import org.squeryl.dsl._

  implicit val timeTEF = new NonPrimitiveJdbcMapper[Long, DateTime, TLong](longTEF, this) {
    def convertFromJdbc(t: Long) = DateTime(t)
    def convertToJdbc(t: DateTime) = t.timestamp
  }

  implicit val optionTimeTEF =
    new TypedExpressionFactory[Option[DateTime], TOptionLong]
      with DeOptionizer[Long, DateTime, TLong, Option[DateTime], TOptionLong] {

    val deOptionizer = timeTEF
  }

  implicit def timeToTE(s: DateTime) = timeTEF.create(s)

  implicit def optionTimeToTE(s: Option[DateTime]) = optionTimeTEF.create(s)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected answer :

You are importing the org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode companion object
and also your own extension (object DateTime extends PrimitiveTypeMode)

You can only use on or the other in a same application (see http://squeryl.org/0.9.6.html)

The org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode companion object is now deprecated (the trait with the same name isn't)

Old (wrong) answer :

You don't need to register your custom types, the register is only for primitive JDBC types, it is a closed set.

See this example : https://github.com/max-l/squeryl-extended-field-types-example
JodaDate is backed by the (already registered) Timestamp primitive type.

Comment: This is exactly my first link. The problem is that apparently my extended primitive type is not registered, although I think I do the same as the example. I will post my model in the question body.

Comment: you say : my extended primitive type is not registered, do you mean the primitive type that backs my custom type is not registered ? Because you cannot extend the set of primitive types, it is a closed set.

Comment: What I mean is that looking at the source I think that the instance `timeTEF` of `NonPrimitiveJdbcMapper` should be registered during creation. Still I get an error like `Usupported native type models.fields.DateTime,models.fields.DateTime`. If I understand correctly, this exception is fired from `FieldMapper.get` when the lookup of the `JDBCMapper` in the registry fails. That is, I am lead to think that `private [squeryl] def register[P,A](m: NonPrimitiveJdbcMapper[P,A,_])` is not called for my field. If this is not clear, please tell me, so that I can expend the question.

Comment: I apologize if the terminology is not very clear, but I do not know how to call the new fields that are available in 0.9.6 - primitive and custom types are already taken :-)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, register(m: NonPrimitiveJdbcMapper) does need to have been called for your custom type. Can you dump the registry after timeTEF is created (like at the end of DateTime initialization), or even better, put a compilable example on GitHub ?

Comment: Thank you for your help; I will try to extract a minimal example from the application, but it is not easy, since it is a not trivial Play! project.

Comment: It seems that when I extract the relevant part, it all works correctly. I will try dumping the registry

Comment: Following the source I see that the content of the registry is already dumped when the exception occurs, and it is already in the body of the question. It is the portion of the stacktrace that caught my attention in the first place. I do not see any extended primitive type in there.

Comment: My guess is that you have more than one PrimitiveTypeMode instance, DateTime would be one, and the PrimitiveTypeMode object could be the other. The Schema class takes an implicit FieldMaper as argument, please check if it is your DateTime object that is being passed to it.

Comment: I am considering deprecating the PrimitiveTypeMode object, if you happen to be importing it in scope, you would get the kind of behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! It is really nice to see the author of a library I am using giving help on StackOverflow. :-) This has already happened with Eric Torreborre when I had a problem with Specs2. Maybe you can consider updating the answer with the actual issue, so that it is not buried in the comments.